# How to make different icon url in laravel breadcrump?

Tags: laravel

Hi guys i have trouble in making different icon for url using laravel breadcrump, , here the picture

[image]

I want to make icon HRMS and Dashboard is different

Here my blade file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset("/css/hrms2.css") }}">

@if (count($breadcrumbs))

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        @foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb)

            @if ($breadcrumb->url && !$loop->last)
                <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="">
                    <a class="bread-color" href="{{ $breadcrumb->url }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> {{ $breadcrumb->title }}</a>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ $breadcrumb->title }}</li>
            @endif

        @endforeach
    </ol>

 @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass icon name also in `$breadcrumb` object and use `$breadcrumb->icon` instead of `fa-home`

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
@foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb)

    @if ($breadcrumb->url && !$loop->last)
       <li class="breadcrumb-item" style=""><a class="bread-color" href="{{ $breadcrumb->url }}"> <i class="fa {{ $breadcrumb->icon }}"></i> {{ $breadcrumb->title }}</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ $breadcrumb->title }}</li>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by `make default icon instead image icon`?

Comment: Sory for that , i want ask anymore ,  so what fill of the icon?? is it 'fa fa-home' or image.extension(jpg.png)'

Comment: `fa fa-home` itself gets the icon from `font awesome` library. you only need to change `fa-home` as per your need . For more information https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: <i class="fa fa-{{{ $breadcrumb->icon }}}"></i>, this is the solution of my problem

Comment: do you have icon stored in your object? if yes then yes this is the solution